# How to change extents in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, extents

I'm trying to learn QGIS. How do I change the Extents (Highlighted in green below).
I tried to make a custom CRS, but I couldn't figure out a way to change these.

[image]

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html#custom-coordinate-reference-system

Comment: Thank you for the link, I've read that page and couldn't find any mention of how to change the Extent values, could you please clarify your comment?

Comment: According to the QGIS user manual, in order to define a custom coordinate system you would have to learn to use PROJ.4. The manual recommends [this article](https://pubs.usgs.gov/of/1990/0284/report.pdf). I glanced through that article and wasn't able to find an easy answer to your question. Maybe if you edit your question and explain exactly what CRS you want to define, someone who understands proj4 will do it for you.

Comment: Thanks csk, I'm not sure exactly how to write the Extents. I would like it centered on -90,0 (half the globe on either side). Other than that I want to use the standard WGS 84.